# Backreference in tf.strings.regex_replace

Tags: python, regex, string, tensorflow

I want to remove repeated characters e.g. hhhh, verrrry from a given string using tf.strings.regex_replace. I used the following expression

```
lcased = tf.strings.regex_replace(lcased, r'(.)\1{2,}', r'\1')  # repeated chars
```

But it throughs an error

```
"tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Invalid pattern: (.)\1{2,}, error: invalid escape sequence: \1 [Op:StaticRegexReplace]"
```

Comment: The regex library used in this [`tf.strings.regex_replace`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/strings/regex_replace) function is RE2, and it does not support backreferences.

Comment: Is there a work around to achieve the same result?

Comment: Yes, spell out all possibilities... But this is hardly a reasonable workaround for all Unicode letters.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code below as a workaround to remove repeated characters from a string.

```
import re    
s = s = 'verrrry, hhhhhh'
new_s = re.sub(r'([a-z])\1+', r'\1', s)
print(new_s) #very, h
```